# Skyscraper from bottom art

Tags: style-identification

[image]

I was wondering.. What do you call this skyscraper art? 
If you could give me references, that would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a perspective drawing. Specifically, it's using 'single point (or one point)' perspective.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)#One-point_perspective

In this case, the vanishing point (the one point where all the perspective lines converge) is directly up. So you are looking up at the world which, as Jory points out, is often called worms-eye view (as opposed to looking down on the world, which is called birds-eye view).

This particular drawing is a bit wonky in that all the perspective line don't actually converge into an exact point, but rather a 'blobby area in the middle'. I think they may have stretched the center portion of the drawing to fit the back of the macbook. However, the general perspective is still there and you can see roughly that the vanishing point of this drawing is roughly dead center:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a specific term for pictures of skyscrapers, other than skyscrapers.
The perspective is called **frog perspective**.
Maybe **stencil** could work as a keyword for the black and white art style.

Comment: I've heard frog perspective also referred to as "worm's eye view" or, as DA01 mentioned above, "single-point perspective" or "one-point perspective"

Comment: I mean frog's perspective. Seems to me like we are looking up to the sky.

Comment: Oops :) I don't spend much time in nature nor lying on my back between skyscrapers. I try to average between these two.